I want my spinner box index to determine the zoom of the map
I am making a app that shows roadworks near the user, I have implemented a map and and a spinner box with three options I want my spinner box index to determine how zoomed in my map is. when I compile my code it will zoom in to the default zoom set however when I select another option from the drop down nothing happens.
This is my map callback
     ` private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback { googleMap ->
            /**
             * Manipulates the map once available.
             * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
             * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera.
             * In this case, we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
             * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to
             * install it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the
             * user has installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
             */
    
            val (latitude, longitude) = getLocation()
            currentLocation = LatLng(latitude, longitude)
            googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current location"))
            
            //Moves the camera to  users position with the zoom level
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, selectedZoomLevel))
        }` 
    

This is my spinner on item selected listener
    binding.searchSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {

                //gets the array of items for the spinner
                val spinnerItems = resources.getStringArray(R.array.spinner_items)

                // Zoom levels based off of my spinner items
                val zoomLevels = mapOf(
                    "10 km" to 12.0f,
                    "25 km" to 8.0f,
                    "50 km" to 2.0f
                )

                // Retrieve selected item and make it a string
                val selectedItem = binding.searchSpinner.selectedItem.toString()

                // Sets the zoom level based on selected item, otherwise default to 12.0f
                selectedZoomLevel = zoomLevels[selectedItem] ?: 12.0f

                // Call showToastWithIndex with the selected position
                showToastWithIndex(requireContext(), spinnerItems, position)


            }


You need to call moveCamera() or animateCamera() method inside your onItemSelectedListener for the map zoom to change
First is you need to make sure that you create a global variable for your Google Maps instance using lateinit:
private lateinit var gMap: GoogleMap

Then insert the GoogleMap instance within it once the map loads:
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    gMap = googleMap
    //..other code..//
}

There are other ways to do this like passing the googleMap as a parameter. But ultimately, this will help you access it later on within your onItemSelectedListener.
So when you have done this, you can add the moveCamera() or animateCamera() within onItemSelectedListener and everything should work fine.
The onItemSelectedListener code you provided should look something like this:
binding.searchSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(
        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
        view: View?,
        position: Int,
        id: Long
    ) {
    
    //gets the array of items for the spinner
    val spinnerItems = resources.getStringArray(R.array.spinner_items)
    
    // Zoom levels based off of my spinner items
    val zoomLevels = mapOf(
        "10 km" to 12.0f,
        "25 km" to 8.0f,
        "50 km" to 2.0f
    )
    
    // Retrieve selected item and make it a string
    val selectedItem = binding.searchSpinner.selectedItem.toString()
    
    // Sets the zoom level based on selected item, otherwise default to 12.0f
    selectedZoomLevel = zoomLevels[selectedItem] ?: 12.0f
    
    // Call showToastWithIndex with the selected position
    showToastWithIndex(requireContext(), spinnerItems, position)

    // Since you can access googleMaps here, you can call the animateCamera / moveCamera method here:
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, selectedZoomLevel))
    // or...
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, selectedZoomLevel))    
}

Here's a sample code I made as a proof of concept
MapsActivity.kt:
package com.example.kotlindemos

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.Toast

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import com.example.kotlindemos.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    val SYDNEY = LatLng(-33.862, 151.21)
    val ZOOM_LEVEL = 13f
    private lateinit var gMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var spinner: Spinner

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_map_demo)
        val mapFragment : SupportMapFragment? =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as? SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)

        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)

        val listItems = listOf("10 km", "25 km", "50 km")

        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listItems)
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinner.adapter = arrayAdapter

        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {

                val selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

                // Zoom levels based off of my spinner items
                val zoomLevels = mapOf(
                    "10 km" to 12.0f,
                    "25 km" to 8.0f,
                    "50 km" to 2.0f
                )

                // Sets the zoom level based on selected item, otherwise default to 12.0f
                val selectedZoomLevel = zoomLevels[selectedItem] ?: 12.0f

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Selected: $selectedZoomLevel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                // Since we have confirmed that the zoom level values are correct, we can now use them to set the zoom level
                gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SYDNEY, selectedZoomLevel))
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                // write code to perform some action
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just move the camera to Sydney and add a marker in Sydney.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        gMap = googleMap
        with(gMap) {
            moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SYDNEY, ZOOM_LEVEL))
            addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(SYDNEY))
        }
    }
}

layout.xml:

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.kotlindemos.BasicMapDemoActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<!--    insert spinner-->
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        />
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.kotlindemos.BasicMapDemoActivity">

    </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>

</LinearLayout>


